# How to call a contract's function in Nethereum?

Tags: nethereum

I'm trying to call a contract's function but get an error "Function not found". I've made a test contract from this topic https://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/contracts/calling-transactions-events/ on bsc testnet, and it works good - I can call a "multiply" function using contract.GetFunction("multiply");
But I can't call any function at mainnet and get this error.
This is a contract address 0x23567C7299702018B133ad63cE28685788ff3f67 and there are a lot of functions. I tried to call all functions and got an error.
Here is the example of my code:

```
const string walletKey = "...";
const int binanceMainnetChainId = 56;
const string binanceMainnetJsonRpc = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/";
var account = new Account(walletKey, binanceMainnetChainId);
var web3 = new Web3(account, binanceMainnetJsonRpc);
web3.TransactionManager.UseLegacyAsDefault = true;
var transaction = new TransactionInput();
transaction.From = account.Address;
var estimateGas = await web3.TransactionManager.EstimateGasAsync(transaction);
transaction.Gas = estimateGas;
string abi = @"...";
var contract = web3.Eth.GetContract<string>(contractAddress);
var function = contract.GetFunction("owner");  // Here I got an error
```

Comment: I want to know the same thing